# Monkey Tail Cactus Burned under lights do I have to move it?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, succulents, cactus, grow-lamp

My Monkey Tail Cactus hangs down really low, so I have to raise it up to keep it from touching the ground.  When I raise it up it gets closer to the grow light.  The last time I raised it up I burned it.  It has a yellow spot.   Do I have to lower it or can I still keep it that close to the light.  Last time I raised higher than I needed to, so it can be lowered.  But, don't want to if I don't have to.

You can see from picture one that I burned the Crassula as well. The Crassula has permanent burn marks, but that's okay. The Adromischus is also yellow from the lights as well.  I know it will turn back to its normal colour once I move it.

I just don't want the plant to blister and rot because I didn't lower the plant.
Sorry the colour is off.  The grow lights make everything yellow in pictures.  The colour of the cactus is good.  The yellow part is firm.

[image: close up]
[image: Far shot]

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is still firm it is okay. I don't know why you wouldn't want to move it.  You know it is under stress.  Stressed plants are more likely to get bugs and disease.  If you could keep your cactus happy then do it.  You are not helping anything by leaving it where it is.

That Crassula/Jade Plant will continue to get burn marks on it if you do not move it.  Again, you are asking for other problems keeping you plants stressed.

I would also space out your plants more. Give them more air movement. You have stressed plants that are jammed packed together.  Even touching each other. Those points of contact will hold in moisture.  Moisture could lead to rot or other fungal disease.

I think you have more or potentially more problems than one burned cactus.

Comment: Though you information is correct, you tone is not.   If he has fan going or some way to move the air it's okay to have the plants that close.  Your comments about plants touching has nothing to do with the question and does nothing towards helping answer the question.

Comment: When I started growing cacti 50 or so years ago, I often got nasty burning when I brought the plants out from their dark winter cave, into full sunlight. Now I bring them out into part shade for a few weeks before subjecting them to full sun. I no longer get burn. Unless you also have temperature trouble, you might get by with just turning down the lights for a while. Cacti normally love full sun. Even hobbit jades.

Comment: I do have a fan.  Cactus only plant touching other plants.  Spines keep it not touching directly.   @WayfaringStranger I have to remove all the plants to take the light down to dim it.  Easier to lower the plants.  I have very thin garden cloth I used to protect seedlings from light.  Should I use that?

Comment: That might work.